# Mongoexport: Distinct in query exporting 0 rows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can not understand why is not working:

```
mongoexport --db i-log  --collection log -query "{distinct: 'ip_address' }"
```

Result:exported 0 records

but when I run query:

```
db.log.distinct("ip_address")
```

result:1163 records

Here, too, so it is impossible:

```
mongoexport --db i-log  --collection log -f ip_address -query "{distinct: 'ip_address' }"
```

and if 'distinct' not supported how, then export the non-recurring column values?

check this option, a little something, but does not work

```
mongoexport --db i-log  --collection log -f ip_address  --query "{find ({},{ip_address: 1, _id: 0 } )}"
```

Comment: `mongoexport` doesn't support `distinct` queries.  What your command does is export docs that have a field named 'distinct' with a value of 'ip_address' (which is why it returns no records).

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for your propose:

1. Create a Js file, on your linux shell.
2. Put the slaveOk, if necessary and the database you need to use,
       before the query, that you will edit in the js file.
3. Put the query after the all things I mentioned above and then, call
       that for mongo client, for this form below:

`mongo -u userName -p userPass AuthDB < js_filename.js > js_output.txt`

The results that you need, you be there at the `js_output.txt`.